# Highlight Excel Sheet when Data Values Change from Auto-Refresh?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I'm working on a New Item Tracker for the enterprise I work for. I need VBA macro that will highlight a cell if the value has changed after a data refresh from another sheet I import weekly. (The Sheet is running off Vlookups)

Ex: Cell W10 Contains a Vlookup to another sheet that is imported weekly, I would like cell W10 to be highlighted and display a message if this cell changes after a new import. Here is the code I'm currently using.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A10:W200")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
End If
End Sub
```

it will display a message if a manual cell change is made, but not after a data refresh, and it won't highlight the cell. Can anyone please assist with this?

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` won't be fired if a formula is recalculated. The only way to achieve what you want is to copy the old data to a "previous version"-sheet prior to refreshing the data. Then you should be able to use conditional formatting to highlight changes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. That should be feasible. How would I alter the code to also highlight changes once I paste over the values? Or would this change only be applicable if I switch to conditional formatting?

Comment: Without knowing your exact data: with conditional formatting you won't need VBA at all - I assume

Answer (score 0):

with workbook open and sheet calculate

in added module

```
Public oldArray As Variant
```

in workbook module - edit sheet name accordingly

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        ' Store old range values in oldArray if not already done

        If IsEmpty(oldArray) Then
            oldArray = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A10:W200").Value
        End If
End Sub
```

in sheet module

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim newArray As Variant
    Dim changedCells As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

        ' Store new range values in newArray
        newArray = Range("A10:W200").Value

        ' Compare old and new values for each cell
        For i = LBound(newArray, 1) To UBound(newArray, 1)
            For j = LBound(newArray, 2) To UBound(newArray, 2)
                If newArray(i, j) <> oldArray(i, j) Then
                    ' Store changed cell address
                    Set cell = Range("A10").Offset(i - 1, j - 1)
                    changedCells = changedCells & cell.Address & ", "
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        ' Output changed cell addresses in msgbox
        If Len(changedCells) > 0 Then
            changedCells = Left(changedCells, Len(changedCells) - 2)
            MsgBox "The following cells have changed: " & changedCells
        End If

        ' Update oldArray with new values
        oldArray = newArray
End Sub
```